# How to tell the SAP UI5 Declarative Compiler to not use addContent on view but placeAt instead?

Tags: sapui5

I have a view defined as follows:

```
<template data-controller-name="MyController">
  <div class="circle colorBlack"><span data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.Label" id="percentPointsWon">48</span>%</div>                       
</template>
```

The resulting code after calling the view looks like this:

```
<div class="circle colorBlack"><span></span>%</div>
<label id="pointsWonOnServeView--percentPointsWon" data-sap-ui="pointsWonOnServeView--percentPointsWon" style="" class="sapUiLbl sapUiLblNowrap">50</label>
```

The problem is, that the label element is not inserted into the span as one would assume but at the end of the view code.

Looking at the sourcecode (sap/ui/core/DeclarativeSupport-dbg.js) this is obvious when looking at these lines:

```
if (oView && !isRecursive) {
    oView.addContent(oControl);
} else {
    oControl.placeAt(oElement);
}
```

How can I enforce that the control is not placed at the end of my view code but exactly at the declaring element? Looking at the code I assume that oView must be null but how can I enforce that?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in HTML views would be declared as div's

```
<div class="circle colorBlack"><div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.commons.Label" id="percentPointsWon">48</div>%</div>
```

Comment: I've tried replacing the SPAN with a DIV but that did not lead to the desired effect.